# ActiveRecord where condtion on selected query result

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

```
Borrower.joins("INNER JOIN receivables ON receivables.borrower_id = borrowers.id")
.where("borrowers.type='moulde_b'")
.select(" borrowers.id as id,sum(receivables.amount) as invoice_amount");
```

from the above result set I'm trying to do **where** condition after the select statement.

I'm trying something like the below,

```
Borrower.joins("INNER JOIN receivables ON receivables.borrower_id = borrowers.id")
    .where("borrowers.type='moulde_b'")
    .select(" borrowers.id as id,sum(receivables.amount) as invoice_amount").where("receivables.amount = 12323.23");
```

is this really possible to do after select **where** condtion on the **SUM** column.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#having`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-having) instead of `where`:

```
Borrower.
  joins("INNER JOIN receivables ON receivables.borrower_id = borrowers.id").
  where("borrowers.type = 'moulde_b'").
  select("borrowers.id as id, sum(receivables.amount) as invoice_amount").
  group("borrowers.id"). # mandatory for having
  having("invoice_amount = 12323.33")
```

The order of chaining these methods does not really matter, since `AR` would rearrange it while building the real SQL query anyway.